# HttpQueryInfo to get File Size

Tags: c++, winapi

Why does this function work on a direct url to a download however fail on a php page echoing out a file for download? (GetLastError is 0)

Comment: with which [*Query Info Flags*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/query-info-flags) ? not all information exist in headers. query `HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF` first for example for understand - are exist info which you query

Comment: How does the function fail to work, does it error, or does it return a wrong value?

Comment: It returns an invalid size which leads to InternetReadFile not being able to work. Maybe I have to set the size in the php header info to get it to work?

Comment: A content length is not sent if the server is streaming the response data dynamically and so doesn't know the final size up front. Check with `HTTP_QUERY_TRANSFER_ENCODING` to see if the server is using the `"chunked"` encoding to send data dynamically or not. Otherwise, just ignore `HttpQueryInfo()` and go straight to `InternetReadFile()` until it has no more data to give. Whether the response is static or dynamic, `InternetReadFile()` will know when to stop reading

Answer (score 2):

Not all HTTP requests will have a content length field in the response. Dynamic pages generated by PHP scripts might not know how large the content actually is.

In these cases you need just need to read a little bit at the time until there is no more data returned from the server.

Comment: That makes sense. Would setting Content-Length in the header of the php file not fix this however?

Comment: It would for files that are stored on the server. For dynamic content that is generated on the fly it depends on the server, some are able to cache the page content and calculate the size and some just stream the content without knowing the size.